# How can I add shadow color below the line in chart.js charts?

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

This is my current code for line chart and it shows the normal chart but I want color shadow below the line. I have added the image of the same way I want to make it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC2xZ.png)

```js
var myChart = new Chart("lineChart", {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
          backgroundColor: "#F72585",
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 13, 3],
          fill: false,
          // borderDash: [],
          borderOffset: 0.0,
          borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
          borderBackgroundColor: '#F72585',
          pointBorderColor: '#F72585',
          // pointBorderWidth: 1,
          pointHoverRadius:5,
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#F72585',
          pointHoverBorderColor: '#F72585',
          // pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
          // pointRadius: 1,
          // pointHitRadius: 10,
          tension: 0,
          borderColor: "#F72585",
          
          pointBackgroundColor: "#F72585",
          borderWidth: 1
        }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Total Price'
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Product Category'
            }
          }]
        },
        plugins: {
          filler: {
            propagate: true
          }
        },
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem) {
              return tooltipItem.xLabel;
            },
            title: function(tooltipItem) {
              return 'Total Price  '+tooltipItem[0].yLabel;
            }
          },
          position: 'nearest',
          intersect: false,
          yPadding: 10,
          xPadding: 10,
          caretSize: 8,
          titleFontColor: '#1A202C',
          backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
          bodyFontColor: 'Black',
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: It would be better to play and try with code, if you can create a stackblitz and reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have created project but I dont know how to install library in stackblitz. Please find the image in my question for reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In highcharts, it is possible with chart type 'area'. Check the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs-c4btq1?file=app/line-chart/line-chart.component.ts) I have updated here and its working

For Chart JS, you can Set the fill property to +1 of a dataset will set the backgroundColor from this line to the next line in dataset.

```
datasets: [{
    label: 'India',
    data: [],
    fill: '+1',
    borderColor: '#FFC108',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,193,8,0.2)'
  },
  {
    label: 'USA',
    data: [],
    fill: true,
    borderColor: '#FFC108',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
  }]
```

Check this in chartjs [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/area/line-datasets.html) [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ke5n5LnL/26/)

Comment: @KaleSunit for shadow color you can use gradient option, here is a [link](https://blog.vanila.io/chart-js-tutorial-how-to-make-gradient-line-chart-af145e5c92f9) of few examples.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will check how I can use gradient option as per my need.